# CoffeeScript source maps loaded but sources not fetched by Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript, source-maps

I'm trying to get source maps to work for my CoffeeScript in Chrome. I can see that `coffee` is generating the source maps properly, and in fact Chrome's dev tools shows that the source map file is fetched successfully from my local HTTP server.

However, the `.coffee` file itself isn't being fetched, even though I am able to `GET` it manually in the browser.

I suspect this might have something to do with the directory structure. The directory from which I'm serving HTTP (using a simple python server) looks like this:

```
./
  index.html ("includes" 'lib/coffeedrag.js)
  src/
    coffeedrag.coffee
  lib/
    coffeedrag.js
    coffeedrag.map
```

So, when I open `index.html` in the browser, the `.js` and `.map` files are fetched properly. The `.map` file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "coffeedrag.js",
  "sourceRoot": "..",
  "sources": [
    "src/coffeedrag.coffee"
  ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": "[ trimmed for brevity ... ]"
}
```

What could be stopping Chrome from fetching `coffeedrag.coffee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome loads the source maps file for a JS file from a little comment in the file, like so:

```
/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
*/
```

Usually this is stripped out of the CoffeeScript compiler unless you specify the `--bare` flag: http://coffeescript.org/#usage

Eg in my `Gruntfile.coffee` I have:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    coffee:
      dev:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'assets/js/'
        dest: '<%= coffee.dev.cwd %>'
        ext: '.js'
        src: [
          '*.coffee'
          '**/*.coffee'
        ]
        options:
          bare: true
          sourceMap: true
```

This then opens up the CoffeeScript files to Chrome:

[image: screenshot of Chrome]

And if I add a `debugger` in my code, per sa, I get:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, the map file is indeed loaded by Chrome and naturally the source-map comment is generated as expected. But still, Chrome doesn't load the coffee files.

Comment: Oh I see, but why would Chrome load the coffee files? Chrome can't natively execute CoffeeScript and since your app isn't linking to the files in any way apart from in the source maps comment, it wouldn't appear in the Network tab.

Comment: Fair enough. I assumed that it would use http to load the coffee file just like it loaded the map file, so if one appears in the network tab so should the other. Now I see that when I add a breakpoint in JS it indeed breaks into the coffee files. Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want to load the CoffeeScript file?

Comment: I want to be able to do "view source" of a page and see coffee. That's all.

Comment: So you can do that in the Sources tab. In that first screenshot I posted you can see where Chrome has found the CoffeeScript files that relate to my JS files.

Comment: I used source maps and I had that exact same problem in Chrome. The trick is really to go to the sources tab and click on the tiny button in the upper left corner which has the tooltip "Show navigator" and click on the `*.coffee` file there. Yep, there's your neat source code. You can still view the compiled js files there, too.